# Capture events from other windows applications

Tags: c#, windows

I have a third party application which I did not create myself. I need to create an application which is able to listen for button clicks and read data from tables in that application. I believe that the third party application is made in C# but I do not know for sure. Is there a way to know when UI buttons are pressed and to harvest data from the application? I do not mind which programming language the solution must be written in, as long as it fulfils the above tasks.

Comment: Can you access the other application source code?

Comment: No, it was downloaded from the internet and I am trying to create a kind of interface that displays the data in that application more clearly, and performs actions when buttons are pressed in the third party one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use few dlls like user32.dll, to get data from other apps.
Find parent handle of a window:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

public static IntPtr FindWindow(string windowName)
{
    var hWnd = FindWindow(windowName, null); 
    return hWnd;
}
```

After that, find handle of a child window

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className,  string windowTitle);

private IntPtr FindSomeElement(IntPtr parent)
{
    IntPtr childHandle;

childHandle = FindWindowEx(
    parent,    
    IntPtr.Zero,    
    "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app21", 
    IntPtr.Zero);   
return childHandle;}
```

and get text from it:

```
private static string GetText(IntPtr childHandle)
{
    const uint WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
    const uint WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;

    var length = (int)SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, null);
    var sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
    SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)sb.Capacity, sb);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

//I didnt test this code, just gave an idea. 
Visit www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ for more information. You can find alot about user32.dll

Comment: also SPY++ would help u to get element class name or main window class name.

Comment: What language is this written in?

Comment: @JPadley, it's c#

Comment: Can you provide links to any tutorials?

Comment: @JPadley https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/825946/Csharp-VB-NET-and-WinAPI-How-to-Access-Window-of-O and alot more u can find in google.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it!

Comment: After researching your suggestion, I fail to see how this fulfills the question. How can I detect UI Button Presses or harvest data using this method? Or is there another way that this can be accomplished?